# ROSLIB.Param.get() callback not executing

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosparam, getparam, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

Not sure if something is broken, or if I am doing something wrong. I have started the bridge, and got to the point where when I load the page:

```
var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
        url: 'ws://localhost:9090'
    });
ros.on('connection', function() {
        console.log('Connected to websocket server.');
    });
```

Result:

`"Connected to websocket server."`

However, I have some parameters already on the server under the namespace `/lookup`. These were loaded in from a yaml file with rosparam load. When I attempt to load these values, I get no callback behavior:

```
var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
        url: 'ws://localhost:9090'
    });

var lookup = new ROSLIB.Param({
        ros : ros,
        name : '/lookup'
    });

ros.on('connection', function() {
        console.log('Connected to websocket server.');
        lookup.get(function(value){
            console.log("Lookup: "+value);
        });
        console.log('Ended connection sequence');
    });
```

Result:

`"Connected to websocket server."`
`"Ended connection sequence"`

No errors, but no printing of my info.

I also verified that I am able to use the set command, and these parameters get set and are visible when running `rosparam get <parameter>`. When I tried to get this parameter with the above logic, however, it never executed the callback, as with the others.

I also tried with ros.getParams, but that didn't work either. Am I doing something incorrectly?
Also, using ros-kinetic, if that helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297565/roslib.param.get()-callback-not-executing/) by [AndrewJSchoen](https://answers.ros.org/users/36496/andrewjschoen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-11-07**:
I'm facing a similar issue. By any chance, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem, and I ended up realizing the communication between ROS and the socket wasn't bi-directional. `web` --> `ros` was alright, but `ros` --> `web` was not. In other words, I could publish messages using `roslibjs` but not subscribe to a topic (nor get parameters, etc).

I ended up in [this issue](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/336), and in particular, [this comment](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/336#issuecomment-398541498). I reinstalled `twisted` using `pip` and `roslibjs` started working properly again.

Your issue might have a different cause, but this solution worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0